# Dynamic Proxy without explicitely specifying the type in scala

Tags: scala, dynamic, proxy

is it possible to have a method that takes an arbitrary instance and returns a java.reflection.Proxy or similar that has the same type as the original argument?

I guess it should look something like this:

```
def createProxy[S](model: S)(implicit manifest: Manifest[S]): S = {...}
```

or this

```
def createProxy[S, T<:S](model: S)(implicit manifest: Manifest[S]): T = {...}
```

where T is the subtype of S which results from a combination of all the implemented interfaces, since it doesn't seem like I can Proxy an actual class, but only interfaces.

Comment: a bit old but yet... the proxy can be cast to interface only, not to a concrete class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should do the trick.  Note that it can't return an S since it's likely S is not an interface.

```
import java.lang.reflect._

def createProxy[S](model: S)(implicit manifest: Manifest[S]) = {
  val clazz = manifest.erasure 
  Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader, clazz.getInterfaces, new InvocationHandler() {
    def invoke(proxy:Object, method:Method, args:scala.Array[Object]) = {
      method.invoke(model, args:_*)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: The result type is Object so it doesn't solve my problem. Looks like I can't have what I want, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the situations when you want to proxy an object using single interface you can do something like this (based on Hiram Chirino answer):

```
import java.lang.reflect.{Method, InvocationHandler, Proxy}

def createProxy[I](proxee: I, interfaceClass: Class[I]): I = {
  assert(interfaceClass.isInterface, "interfaceClass should be an inteface class")
  Proxy.newProxyInstance(interfaceClass.getClassLoader, Array(interfaceClass), new InvocationHandler() {
    override def invoke(proxy: Object, method: Method, args: Array[Object]) = {
      println("before")
      val result = method.invoke(proxee, args: _*)
      println("after")
      result
    }
  }).asInstanceOf[I]
}
```

And having an interface `SessionSvc` use it like this:

```
val sessionSvc = createProxy(new SessionSvcMongo, classOf[SessionSvc])
```

This way I managed to introduce rather painless AOP into cake pattern based codebase.